AIDL file is not getting compiled
The documentation says the file should get created in the directory app/build/generated/source/aidl/debug/ after compiling but the source folder isnt getting created in the generated
I tried this Download the ISystemPolicy.aidl file, unzip it and copy it to the src/main/aidl directory of your Android project. If the aidl directory does not exist, please create it manually. Make sure the file name is the same as the interface name, which is src/main/aidl/com/easycontrol/mdm/ISystemPolicy.aidl.

Compile the AIDL File
After saving the AIDL file, synchronize your project in Android Studio to ensure that the AIDL file is correctly compiled into a Java interface file. The compiled files are typically located in the app/build/generated/source/aidl/debug/ directory.


I had similar issue when upgraded gradle plugin version. They introduced new parameter for aidl interfaces which is disabled by default. You need to enable it in your gradle config file like this:
android.buildFeatures.aidl true

